# Java calls shell, zip command in script often fails

Tags: java, linux, shell, zip

Java code

```
try {
        String command = "/opt/compress.sh param1 param2 param3";
        Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        ps.waitFor(60 * 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();

        log.info("shell log：\n" + result);
    }finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

shell Code

```
#Other business codes
zip -m -jP $3 ${zipOutPath} ${fileIputPath}
```

The workflow engine calls jar packages to execute Java code, and the zip command in the shell often fails.  Manually executing the JAR package on the server is normal.Zip compresses only a CSV   file,the file size is 2G.Try to enable shell Debug, only get -> addling XXx. CSV (%)

Comment: Hello, please provide the error you are getting when executing your Java code. Also can you check manually the script execution to see if this is owrking outside Java context.

Answer (score 0):

You are not consuming output streams properly so this may lead to freeze, and `waitFor` must be after reading STDOUT. Try using `ProcessBuilder` instead and see what errors it reports, it may help you to the next step:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
// No STDERR => merge to STDOUT (or redirect elsewhere)
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();

try(var merged = p.getInputStream()) {
    merged.transferTo(System.out);
}
// Check the executable worked:
int rc = p.waitFor();
if (rc != 0)
    throw new RuntimeException("failed: "+Arrays.toString(cmd));
```